# choose a list of words such that have equal letter frequency

Tags: algorithms, random, uniform-distribution

I have a big list meaning full Words. surely letter frequency of this word list is different for each letter.

Now my problem is to find a way to randomly select words from this word list to a new word list, such that in the new word list letter frequencies be approximately the same (i.e. variance of  letters frequency should be low).

selection of words can be with repetition ( each word can be selected many times)

Comment: If every *q* is followed by a *u* you are strongly discouraging words containing a *u* that is not preceeded by *q*.